# Having trouble w/ inline @media

Tags: css

inline block @media width 100% on resize, isn't working and I'm getting a bit confused, what am I doing wrong.

```
.port{

        background: rgba(79,79,79,.5);
        max-width: 30%;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px; 
        margin-top: 4px;
 }


      @media screen and (max-width: 1200px)
    { .port 
    { box-sizing: border-box;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking something obvious.
I'm looking for there to be three rows of pictures on desktop, and when you use a phone there's a single image instead of a row, at 100%.

Comment: There's a close brace missing in the media query... no idea if it was just overlooked here, or if it's missing in your actual markup. You also need to *overwrite* properties if you want them different, so `max-width: 100%` may be needed.

Comment: It's overlooked here.

Comment: and that's what I call a derp, solved. Thanks.